# R functions: passing arguments with ellipsis

Tags: r

I have a question regarding base R usage. It might be asked before, however I wasn't able to find solution to my problem.

I have a function that calls another function. Arguments to second function are passed using ellipsis (`...`). However, I get error message: `object "OBJECT" not found`.

```
f1 <- function(a, ...) {
    print(a)
    f2(...)
}
f2 <- function(...) {
    print(b == TRUE)
    print(runif(c))
}
f1(2, b = FALSE, c = 2)
```

Which gives me: `Error in print(b == TRUE) : object 'b' not found`.

I know that it is possible to get around this problem using `args <- list(...)` and then calling each argument separately, but I imagine that this gets complicated when having lots of arguments (not only two).

**Question**
How to pass arguments from `f1` to `f2` using ellipsis?

Comment: Since you know what arguments `f2` handles why not define `f2` with specific arguments? Also, apart from `list(...)$`, you can access `...` with `..1` etc if you find it more convenient.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

So the ellipses are used to save you specifying all the arguments of `f2` in the arguments of `f1`. Though when you declare `f2`, you still have to treat it like a normal function, so specify the arguments `b` and `c`.

```
f1 <- function(a, ...) {
    print(a)
    f2(...)
}

# Treat f2 as a stand-alone function
f2 <- function(b, c) {
    print(b == TRUE)
    print(runif(c))
}

f1(2, b=FALSE, c=2)

[1] 2
[1] FALSE
[1] 0.351295 0.9384728
```